# Badly placed hyphen in similar-tag submission block

Tags: feature-request, tags, form-submit

[image]

This made me 0_O for a while, and I was thinking that it's a bug--and wondering how to circumvent it---until I realized that the hyphen in electro-chemistry wasn't a soft hyphen but an actual hyphen. It should read:

```
You are attempting to create the tag electrochemistry ; however the tag
electro-chemistry already exists!
```

(The line break is important)

Please, can this be improved? It's confusing when the line break comes right after the hyphen.

Comment: I know that the line break is browser placed--so why not use something like `<wbr>`? (rather old tag, dunno how encouraged it is nowadays)

Answer (score 3):

Wasn't a soft hyphen? A soft hyphen is just a normal hyphen which isn't visually marked on the page (meant to *allow* a word to be broken in this place, similar to a `<wbr>`). In order to force it to remain one word, they need to use a non-breaking hyphen `U+2011` (or `&#8209;` for the entity).

Also, a `<wbr>` wouldn't do anything. That only specifies that you *can* break it here. But the browser still thinks it can get the `electro-` in on that line, so it gets ignored.

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vFH5V/)

I suppose they could just replace the hyphens with the non-breaking hyphen for the tags when they generate that message.

Comment: Oh right, that's not a soft hyphen.. I confused 'soft hyphen' with whatever-you-call-a-line-break hyphen. And, doesn't the browser adjust to accomodate a nearby linebreak to a wbr? I think wbrs would work (on my mobile, the jsfiddle has working wbrs)

Comment: But a nonbreaking hyphen seems like a good alternative :) Go Unicode!

Comment: @Manishearth: No, they don't. They're really not even meant to be used in fluid text, only to indicate potential breaking points in long words and to indicate potential line breaks in pre-formatted text. In a line like this, it's useless.

Comment: hmmm. OK, then, non breaking hyphen seems fine :)

Comment: @MrLister: It would only be replaced in the message, not the actual tag name.